# Strange log message from EditText from `super.onRestoreInstanceState()` (in a simplest app)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, screen-orientation, android-orientation

I just have a simplest app:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simplestedittext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hello_world" >
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

And whenever i rotate the screen, i got this message in my Eclipse:

> 03-28 09:54:46.624: I/TextView(2778): [android.widget.EditText@405320b0 is not instanceof CheckBox] === ss.text is

If i have typed "aaa" in the EditText box, the message will be:

> 03-28 09:54:53.593: I/TextView(2778): [android.widget.EditText@40541820 is not instanceof CheckBox] === ss.text is aaa

What does that message mean? Is there something wrong with my app?

And, do you have these messages?

## Edit:

<del>Well, just noticed, it is not only occurs whenever screen rotates, it occurs also when switching back to this app.</del> (no, sorry, not anymore)

#### i got a breakthrough!

i am sure that message is output from `super.onRestoreInstanceState();`

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simplestedittext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("before");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        System.out.println("after");
    }
}
```

and output messages become:

```
03-28 10:33:36.515: I/System.out(4147): before
03-28 10:33:36.515: I/TextView(4147): [android.widget.EditText@4053a138 is not instanceof CheckBox] === ss.text is 
03-28 10:33:36.523: I/System.out(4147): after
03-28 10:33:44.328: I/System.out(4147): before
03-28 10:33:44.328: I/TextView(4147): [android.widget.EditText@40549128 is not instanceof CheckBox] === ss.text is aaa
03-28 10:33:44.328: I/System.out(4147): after
```

Hope it helps you helps me :-)

## Edit 2:

Please note: **Nothing** is crashing. i am just curious (and not happy) with that "info" level log message :-/

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testorientation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testorientation.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: Yup. i created this new dummy project for testing.

Comment: Is your app crashing or you are just getting that message? I don't understand it but I just ran it the way you have it and it works fine for me. Can you post your manifest?

Comment: What version sdk are your building it?

Comment: @codeMagic: It's **not** crashing. And posted manifest above. Many thanks!!

Comment: @wtsang02 It's Android 2.2 API 8.

Comment: Try it with newest api. I think its just minor system bug back then. EditText and CheckBox is both a instance of TextView, and maybe system was casting some sort of stuff.

Comment: OOPS sadly i have installed and using the Android 4.2 API 17 now, but i am still having those messages :( i am running on my 2.3.5 mobile phone. By the way, do you have those messages in your Eclipse?

Comment: Well well well well well !!! i have just tested in my 2.2 mobile phone. **NO Strange Log Message** is coming out!! That might be the weird of my 2.3.5 device :-x i am still interested to know how your device behave :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: Just close by itself, also within the `<LinearLayout>`? Same messages are outputting. Nothing is different :-/

Comment: for the layout its fine.  Sometime  changes in XML dosen't trigger a new build. After the change do a clean build and you do not have any code and i am not seeing any issue.

Comment: i have just cleaned all my projects and build it again. This simplest project is newly created with only those codes i provided above (with simplest default manifest also). But after the clean and re-build, i am still having those messages whenever screen rotates. Do you have those messages in your Eclipse? If you could try it out on your side, it would be perfect :-)

Comment: I copied your xml and java and its running without any problem

Comment: @Arju: It is not really "a problem", in certain extent. i am just getting that _annoying_ "info" level log message :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove

super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

from onrestoreinstancestate(); and run again
```

Comment: If `super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);` is removed, it does not give me that message, as we expected :-)

Comment: And, of course, the system **cannot** restore the layout Views automatically. It means the text i typed in the `EditText` field does **not** retain.